# One question about function definition in C++

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I'm reading some material about function pointer in C++, and come across one function definition which I do not understand.
Standard function definition have the form:

```
type name (param...)
```

But the following definition seems a little strange to me. Can anyone explain it to me ?
Thanks.

```
float (*GetPtr1(const char opCode)) (float, float)<br>
{
    if(opCode == '+')
        return &Plus;
    else
        return &Minus; // default if invalid operator was passed
}
```

Note: Plus and Minus are two functions with param (float, float) and return a float.

Comment: it may be better to check 'else if(opCode == '-')' to avoid burning some midnight oil in future

Comment: Topic doesn't tell much about your question.. It should.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rule for reading hairy declarations is to start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that `()` and `[]` bind before `*` (i.e., `*a[]` is an array of pointers, `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function):

```
        GetPtr1                                       -- GetPtr1
        GetPtr1(                 )                    -- is a function 
        GetPtr1(           opCode)                    -- taking a single parameter named opCode
        GetPtr1(const char opCode)                    -- of type const char
       *GetPtr1(const char opCode)                    -- and returning a pointer
      (*GetPtr1(const char opCode)) (            )    -- to a function
      (*GetPtr1(const char opCode)) (float, float)    -- taking two parameters of type float
float (*GetPtr1(const char opCode)) (float, float)    -- and returning float
```

So, if `opCode` is equal to '+', `GetPtr1` will return a pointer to the function `Plus`, and if it's '-', it will return a pointer to the function `Minus`.

C and C++ declaration syntax is expression-centric (much as Bjarne would like to pretend otherwise); the form of the declaration should match the form of the expression as it would be used in the code.

If we have a function `f` that returns a pointer to `int` and we want to access the value being pointed to, we execute the function and dereference the result:

```
x = *f();
```

The type of the *expression* `*f()` is `int`, so the declaration/definition for the function is

```
int *f() { ... }
```

Now suppose we have a function `f1` that returns a pointer to the function `f` defined above, and we want to access that integer value by calling `f1`.  We need to call `f1`, derefence the result (which is the function `f`), and execute it, and then dereference *that* result (since `f` returns a pointer):

```
x = *(*f1())(); // *f1() == f, so (*f1())() == f() and *(*f1())() == *f()
```

The type of the *expression* `*(*f1())()` is `int`, so the decaration/definition for `f1` needs to be

```
int *(*f1())() { return f; }
```

Comment: appreciate the in depth explanation of Right-Left Rule +1

Comment: +1 for expanding out a function pointer in to it's components.  Will help people coming across them for the first time.

Answer (score 16):

GetPtr1 is a function that takes an opcode char and returns a pointer to a function.  The function it returns takes two floats and returns a float.

A lot of times it's easier to read if you do something like this:

```
typedef float (*FloatOperationFuncPtr) (float, float);

FloatOperationFuncPtr GetPtr1(const char opCode)
{
    if(opCode == '+')
        return &Plus;
    else
        return &Minus; // default if invalid operator was passed
}
```

Comment: +1, Much easier to use proper typedefs, you could also add the `C++0x` version, something along the lines of: `typedef std::function<float(float,float)> FloatOperationType;` if my memory serves me right.

Answer (score 5):

Always nice to know about http://cdecl.org for such situations. Be aware that it only works if you remove the parameter names. This is what you get for `float(*GetPtr1(const char ))(float, float)`:

> declare `GetPtr1` as function `(const char)` returning pointer to function `(float, float)` returning `float`

Answer (score 3):

It's a function that takes a `const char` and returns a pointer to a function that takes `float, float` and returns a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

That means a function which takes a character and returns a pointer to a function that takes two floats and returns a float.

Answer (score 1):

GetPtr1 is a function that takes two float as input parameters and returns a pointer to a function. This is much more clear:

```
typedef float(*Func)(float, float);


Func GetPtr1(const char opCode)
{
    if(opCode == '+')
        return &Plus;
    else
        return &Minus; // default if invalid operator was passed
}
```